# Is it possible to have more than one main() method in a C# program?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to have more than one `main()` method (with the same parameters) in a C# console application? If so, how?

Comment: Why would you want to have more than one main?

Comment: Look at this article http://raviranjankr.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/multiple-main-method-in-c/

Comment: What the heck would the second one do?

Comment: @Mehrdad: sit there until you needed it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can have more than one main method, you can specify which to use as the entry point for the application by your compiler. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3eht538%28vs.80%29.aspx) link for more detail.

**Example:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
 

    namespace Multiple_MainClasses
    {
        class A
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I am from Class A");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        class B
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
     
                Console.WriteLine("I am from Class B");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

When you will run this code, you will get a compilation error. To resolve go to project properties in solution explorer or press `ctrl + alt + L`, go to application tab, and Select Class with the method which you want to execute as shown below:

[image]

Comment: What if we have two main method in same class? like.. main() and main(string[] args)

Comment: @TusharKukreti This is a compilation error. The Main method is considered as an entry point only if the signature matches any of the below 2 and the method is static


1. Main(String[])  
2. Main()

Comment: When I have 3 Main functions in different class files, only 2 Main methods available in "Startup object" option in Application property in the project.

Comment: It seems the mentioned link didn't have that matter you pointed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - you can specify custom entry point if you have multiple Main methods. [csc /main](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x3eht538.aspx) contains information on it:

> This option specifies the class that contains the entry point to the program, if more than one class contains a Main method.

```
csc MyClssesWithMain.cs /main:OneOfTheClasses
```

Note: `Main` methods have to be in separate classes as you can't have 2 methods with identical signature in the same class.

Answer (score 3):

The main method is your entry point into your application. Based on articles provided by others, it's syntactically valid to define multiple Main methods, but you have to select a single main method when running your app.  I think it makes more sense to create a single main function and make it flexible by using command line args etc.

Comment: -1 It is possible to have multiple mains, so this answer has false info.

Comment: The article you added does not allow two mains at the same time. It seems like a compiler trick to allow you to define two, but only incorporate one at compile time. I don't view that as having two entry  points into your app

Comment: You could have at as many mains as you have classes. `votes--;`

Comment: Yes, but only one is used. You can't use them at the same time

Comment: That's true, but the statement that "It doesn't make sense", IMO, is pretty presumptuous. It's actually a very easy way to test your class' functionality.

Comment: Ok, the language in my post has been moderated a bit