# changing output of the console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, console

During my job interview, interviewer asked me to change the the console output to print "B" without touching the main method and console!
is this possible? (I tried to change the entry point,but it was not correct) 
I have no idea how to answer this question

```
 class Program
  {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
  }
```

Comment: This a very bad interview question.

Answer (score 6):

Well, your interviewer said you can't touch the console. He didn't say you can't make a new one.

```
public static class Console
{
    public static void WriteLine(string dontCare)
    {
        //Specify System.Console instead of just Console
        System.Console.WriteLine("B"); 
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}
```

*Alternatively*, you can go through with your idea, which was to make a new `Main` method, which prints "B" to the console. For that to work, you just have to tell the compiler which one to actually use. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607951/is-it-possible-to-have-more-than-one-main-method-in-a-c-sharp-program) thread details several ways of doing that.

Comment: Although it can be an answer but comparing to other questions he asked me ,this question which aim this answer  is too Weird.(too simple)

Comment: @stybl the `WriteLine` Method should accept a string argument as you are sending one ;)

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Oops. Corrected

Comment: I still think there should be other ways to tackle this,but +1 for your try;)